# RegEx for matching two words with two capital letters

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I am creating a business card parser and am running into issues with the regex. I have a line that I am reading from my file - String s.

I need to be able to grab a line that contains two words and only two capital letters along with not containing certain words. Below is the regex I have used in the past that works, but I am wanting to make this if else statement with the .matches and !.matches

```
else if ((!s.matches(".*\\b(Technologies|Engineer|Systems|Developer|Company|INC|Analyst|Computers|Technology|@)\\b.*") && (s.matches("^(?!(.*[A-Z]){3,})[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+$"))))

 {
     getName();
 }
```

Comment: `and only two capital letters` ... but `INC` contains _three_ capital letters, yet it is in your whitelist.  Can you explain your logic?

Comment: Why not split on spaces, filter on words 3+ in length and exclude a list of words? No need for regex.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Well, I am very new at this, but my idea was if the line contained 2 capital letters and two words then it would be returned and printed. I know I do not want those words to be counted in that process. I am using regex through out the rest of my project.

Comment: @ctwheels I am required to use regex in this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if [this RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/px5sHD/1/) might be what you may be looking for.

#### Input

```
Technologies Word Word word
Engineer Word Word word
Systems Word word word
Developer Word word word
Company Word word word
INC Word Word Word
Analyst Word word word
Computers Word word word
Technology Word word word
```

#### Output

[image]

If not, you can use that same tool and design a RegEx, you only need to add `{2}` at the end for repeating twice.

For removing certain words, you may not need another matching, you might just add, the list you wish in the beginning of the same [RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/A6JjAR/2/):

```
^(?!Technologies|Engineer|Anything|Else|You|Wish)([A-Z][a-z]+\s){2}
```

#### Output

[image]